# Backbone.js - view not

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I've been following some tutorials to bind the view with the model in backbone.js, but my view does not change when I set a new attribute on the model.

I'm currently working form the console and am appending the "tr" to a "table". After setting the new attributes of the , changes only appear if I re-append.

Code below:

```
window.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName:"tr",
template: _.template("<td><%= first%></td><td><%= last%></td><td><%= sex%></td><td><%= height></td><td><%= weight%></td>"),



initiliaze: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    this.template = template.html;


},

render:function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: `initiliaze`is a SO typo? If not, replace it with `initialize` instead.

Comment: I don't think `initiliaze` is executed coz of typo, if it was being executed, it should throw an error saying `template is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `this.template = template.html` and your code works fine

```
window.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName:"tr",

template: _.template("<td><%= first%></td><td><%= last%></td><td><%= sex%></td><td><%= height></td><td><%= weight%></td>"),

initiliaze: function(){

    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    //this.template = template.html;
},

render:function () {

    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
} 

}); `
```